# 503 when trying to install Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I've got a strange error when trying to install subclipse into a current Eclipse Mars installation. The strange thing about is, that it only happens on a windows 7 machine - and only in eclipse. As soon as I enter the offending URL into the browser, it downloads the .jar file without problems. Additionally, the whole update works without any problems on linux. It doesn't matter if I use the eclipse marketplace or try to install it via "install new software" (version 1.10 or 1.12, doesn't matter).

The error happened for the first time last friday and still happens when I try it now, which seems to make it unlikely (together with the other stuff) that it really is a server error...

```
!MESSAGE HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.8.14.jar
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: HttpComponents connection error response code 503.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifacts(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.DownloadManager.fetch(DownloadManager.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.DownloadManager.start(DownloadManager.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect.completePhase(Collect.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningSession.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileModificationJob.runModal(ProfileModificationJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Has anyone an idea what the reason for this error could be?

Comment: Is that machine behind an Internet proxy/firewall?

Comment: Yes, but the windows and linux machine are behind the same firewall. As is the browser, which allows the download.

Comment: Download the zip and install from local archive.  http://subclipse.tigris.org/files/documents/906/49433/site-1.10.10.zip

Comment: That helped, thanks, but of course we are still curious what the actual problem is. Nobody likes mysterious errors in their network...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have configured Eclipse's proxy settings correctly: **Preferences** > **General** > **Network Connections**. A browser will usually work correctly because it is either automatically configured or pre-configured by the IT department that manages proxies and user desktops.

Comment: No proxy there, sorry. A firewall, yes, but no proxy, so there's nothing to configure. Anyway, some other plugins can be loaded (for example, I was able to install Subversive (I think), but not the connectors for it (so it's basically as useless as subclipse for me).